# How do I parameterize android speech recognition? android.speech.action.RECOGNIZE_SPEECH does not do anything

Tags: android, speech-recognition

How to I properly parameterize the speech recognizer so that it can more easily recognize the words that the user will probably say?

As far as I can tell there is no way.

I believe this site is wrong: http://www.4feets.com/2009/04/speech-recognition-in-android-sdk-15/

According to the site, this code:
    ArrayList< String > potentialResults = new ArrayList< String >();
    potentialResults.add("yellow");
    potentialResults.add("green");
    potentialResults.add("blue");
    potentialResults.add("red");

```
// Create Intent  
Intent intent = new Intent("android.speech.action.RECOGNIZE_SPEECH");
```

Will give a hint to the recognizer that you might say those words. However, it appears to do absolutely nothing. It also conflicts with the google documentation which says:

"An ArrayList of the potential results when performing ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH. Only present when RESULT_OK is returned." This hints that the array is a return value NOT an input.

To test this out try adding:
    ArrayList< String > potentialResults = new ArrayList< String >();
    potentialResults.add("cumin"); 
and try to get the speech recognizer to recognize it. You will find it very difficult.

Does any one have insight into how to properly control the speech recognizer?

Comment: Can you please share your code with us; the code you came up with? I could benefit from your findings and many others will also benefit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If by "control" you mean "supply a list of possible results", I suspect you don't.

I believe you are correct vis a vis the linked-to blog post being wrong. However, AFAIK, the only control you have over the speech is to indicate if it is `LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM` or `LANGUAGE_MODEL_WEB_SEARCH`.

`EXTRA_RESULTS` are the outputs, as you indicate, with the possible matches for the spoken prose. You can see the results used in an [API sample](http://developer.android.com/guide/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/VoiceRecognition.html).

Comment: I was afraid you would say that. Hopefully they will improve the API in the next version of Android. This API they have in version 3 is hard to use.

Comment: @CommonsWare Could you have a look at this please.?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33095771/android-recognizerintent-speech-recognition-returns-result-client-error

Answer (score 1):

What I have come up with to deal with this was to create a database of possibilities. I then take the results and substring them to 2 or 3 characters and query the db for the terms. If someone said red then I would search the db for LIKE 're%' and this is actually pretty accurate for what I need.