# Android RecognizerIntent Speech recognition returns RESULT_CLIENT_ERROR

Tags: android, android-tv

I have implemented search view using Leanback Search Fragment in Android TV App.
It works fine for the keyboard input text. But the voice search returns RESULT_CLIENT_ERROR 99%. However the text appears in the edit text on the screen but does not return in onActivityResult. Once in a bluemoon I get RESULT_OK with correct data in the intent.
Device: Nexus Player

Even the default search works the same way most of the items. Hardly do i get the results via voice. (Search in home screen of nexus player i mean)

I try to get the text using the reference of the SearchEditText no luck but.

The following is the code:

```
  setSpeechRecognitionCallback(new SpeechRecognitionCallback() {
      @Override
      public void recognizeSpeech() {
          try {
              startActivityForResult(getRecognizerIntent(), REQUEST_SPEECH);
          } catch (final ActivityNotFoundException e) {
              Log.d("ActivityNotFoundException",e.toString());
          }
      }
  });
```

onActivityResult

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_SPEECH:
            switch (resultCode) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    setSearchQuery(data, true);
                    break;
                case RecognizerIntent.RESULT_CLIENT_ERROR:
                    Log.d("RESULT_CLIENT_ERROR", String.valueOf(requestCode));
                    break;
            }
    }
}
```

How do i make it work 100% Is there anything I can change in the intent provided?

Comment: I don't know if it is related or not, but how do you set your permission? There was a change for [New permissions requirements for Android TV](http://android-developers.blogspot.sg/2015/09/new-permissions-requirements-for.html).

Comment: I use SpeechRecognitionCallback without record audio permission . As of now i am targetting API 22.

Comment: So it seems permission is no problem...
I'm glad to hear that since there are still few Android TV app developers and I can rarely get feedback!

Comment: Yup its exciting hope it goes high in future. And regarding the question, even the default search works the same way most of the items. Hardly do i get the results via voice. (Search in home screen of nexus player i mean)

Comment: I see, I had never got this situation in home screen search or in [my project](https://github.com/corochann/AndroidTVappTutorial). Maybe it is related to hardware issue or environment issue (bluetooth interference etc)?

Comment: Could be a possibility. tested on two devices same result. Got to try in Bravia.

Comment: It works fantastic on Sony Bravia..!

Comment: That's good to know! So software side seems ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem with Nexus player as even the default search operation of the Nexus Player behaves the same way.

However the same piece of code works 100% fine on Sony Bravia and other Android TVs.